# pythonの__init__でのアトリビュートの追加内容に

Tags: python

pythonのあるプログラムを作っています。
その際に、classを定義した後に、`__init__`の定義をしているのですが、
`self.ccc = self._ddd()`と定義している箇所は、`__init__`に追加した`ccc`というアトリビュートを `_ddd`というアトリビュート名に変更しているという認識で良いか教えてください。
`self.aaa = aaa`は`__init__`に`aaa`というアトリビュートに追加したものを`aaa`と呼ぶことにする。
という風に定義していると認識しています。

```py
class abc(object):

    def __init__(self, aaa, encoding='utf-8'):
        self.aaa = aaa
        self.bbb = bbb
        self.ccc = self._ddd()
```

Comment: 提示されたソースだと、`bbb`とか`self._ddd()`が何処にあってどんなものなのかが不明です。これらヘルプ記事を参考に追記してください。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [再現可能な短いサンプルコードの書き方](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ちなみにこちらの記事を読み解くと参考になるかもしれません。[Pythonにおけるコンストラクタ\_\_init\_\_の使い方｜特徴も解説](https://www.fenet.jp/dotnet/column/tool/7263/), [［Pythonチートシート］クラス定義編](https://atmarkit.itmedia.co.jp/ait/articles/2001/28/news013.html), [【Python入門】クラスの基本を１から解説する―完全版](https://it-biz.online/python/class-2/)

Comment: 「〜というアトリビュート名に変更しているという認識で良いか」「aaaと呼ぶことにする」というのはどういう意味でしょう？
`o = abc(100,200); print(o.ccc)` を行う際, `o.ccc` を参照するたびに `_ddd()`メソッドが呼び出されるはず … という意味？

Comment: [Defining Instance-Level Attributes: the ```__init__``` Method](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module4_OOP/ClassInstances.html#Defining-Instance-Level-Attributes:-the-__init__-Method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

書かれていない情報を補完して考えると、いずれも「その認識は合っていない」でしょう。

「`__init__`に追加した`ccc`というアトリビュート」,「`_ddd`というアトリビュート名に変更している」,「`__init__`に`aaa`というアトリビュートに追加したものを`aaa`と呼ぶことにする」といった考え方/とらえ方は、おそらく [Pythonのオブジェクトとクラスのビジュアルガイド – 全てがオブジェクトであるということ](https://postd.cc/pythons-objects-and-classes-a-visual-guide/) とか [Ptyhonとポインタの覚書](https://qiita.com/Daisy/items/a39e60f530f9adde422c), [組み込みエンジニアの戸惑い　Pythonの変数ってポインタ？](https://www.fsi-embedded.jp/kumico/column/440/) あたりから来ているのかもしれませんが、真意はともかく文章として書くべき内容は以下が正しいでしょう。

- Xxxx「に」追加した、と記述するなら、その対象は`__init__`ではなく`abcクラスのインスタンス`でしょう。
  `__init__`を主体に書くなら`__init__`「で」追加した(orする)となるでしょう。
- 「追加した」という記述も分からなくは無いですが、それよりは`__init__`はコンストラクタなのだから「宣言して初期化した」と記述する方が相応しいでしょう。
- 「というアトリビュート名に変更している」,「と呼ぶことにする」という記述だと何か「リダイレクトするように設定している」風に見えますが、行われていることはそうではなくて「宣言した変数に **代入** している」になるでしょう。
- `self.ccc = self._ddd()`という記述は、「`_ddd`というアトリビュート名に変更している」ではなくて、`()`が付いているので`self._ddd()`を呼び出した結果の戻り値を`self.ccc`に代入しています。
  @oriri さんのコメントの書き方`print(o.ccc)`をすれば、`self._ddd()`が呼び出されるのではなく、単に代入された戻り値が表示されます。

  - `()`を付けない`self.ccc = self._ddd`という記述にすると、`self.ccc`には`self._ddd`メソッドのオブジェクトが代入されます。
    メソッドのオブジェクトが代入されている場合、@oriri さんのコメントの書き方`print(o.ccc)`をすれば、オブジェクトの情報が表示されます。(間接的に)`self._ddd()`を呼び出すためには、`print(o.ccc())`と言う風に`o.ccc`に`()`を付ける必要があります。
- `self.aaa = aaa`も、「と呼ぶことにする」ではなくて、`abcクラスのインスタンス`を作成する際に指定した **最初のパラメータ(aaa)** を`self.aaa`に **代入した** という処理になります。

参考記事
[9.3.2. クラスオブジェクト - 9. クラス](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects)
[9.3.3. インスタンスオブジェクト - 9. クラス](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/classes.html#instance-objects)

[【Python】クラスの基本的な使い方（コンストラクタ・メソッド・インスタンス）](https://office54.net/python/class-constructor-instance)
[Python クラスについて](https://qiita.com/motoki1990/items/376fc1d1f3d59c960f5c)
[pythonのclassについて](https://qiita.com/hiroyuki_mrp/items/140d47df01553091d59a)
[属性の参照について分かりやすく解説](https://codor.co.jp/python/reference-to-attribute)
[12. Pythonのアトリビュート](https://sites.google.com/site/kuraitlab/programing-language/python/attributes)